# Use QUERY to average over the rows corresponding to the last 14 days

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula working however the limit to 14 is limiting the data collection to 14 cells where I need it to limit to 14 days (there may be multiple rows for 1 day. The formula should average the 14 days of data to a 7 day/weekly average.

```
=IFERROR(
  AVERAGE(
    QUERY(A4:M,"select M where (dateDiff(now(), B) < 14) order by A desc limit 14",0)
  )*7
,0)
```

Comment: you already have `dateDiff(..)<14` in your formula, why append the extra `limit 14` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `dateDiff(now(), A) < 14` one should exclude the rows with null A entry, because they happen to pass this condition. So it can look like

```
where A is not null and dateDiff(now(), A) < 14
```

Also, if you are going to average the returned values anyway, just ask `query` to do it for you:

```
=QUERY(A4:M, "select avg(M) where A is not null and dateDiff(now(), A) < 14", 0)
```

Comment: You're welcome. On Stack Overflow, an answer can be marked "accepted" if it solved the problem, by clicking the checkmark next to it.